# How to use dynamic values with RSpec mocks?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

RSpec mocks can return multiple values.

```
allow(die).to receive(:roll).and_return(1, 2, 3)
```

How to return a dynamic value such as:

```
allow(clock).to receive(:time).and_return Time.now.to_i
```

Always returns the first value.

Is it possible to have it evaluate the expression for each call to `time`?

Comment: Be wary about taking this approach. Having non-deterministic behaviour in your tests could leave to painful debugging problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove `and_return` and pass in block:

```
allow(clock).to receive(:time) do
  Time.now.to_i
end
```